# microsoft sql sum values when select suma*(select top 1 value ....)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

Hello I have ran into problem after writing  this code

```
select  suma*(select top 1 [Enantis kursas]
from [išlaidos pajamos] isp
join Kursas as k on ISP.[valiutos trumpinys]=k.[valiutos trumpinys]
where k.[Kurso Laikas] between '2000-12-30' and (select laikas2
from [išlaidos pajamos]
where Aprašymo_Id=ISL.Aprašymo_Id)
and k.[valiutos trumpinys]=(select [valiutos trumpinys]
from [išlaidos pajamos]
where Aprašymo_Id=ISL.Aprašymo_Id)                                            
order by [Kurso Laikas] desc) as suvienodinta_valiuta, tipas, narioID
from [išlaidos pajamos] ISL
join Tipas as T on T.Aprašymo_Id=ISL.Aprašymo_Id
where T.tipas='Paj' and ISL.laikas2 between '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31 23:59:59:999' 
order by suvienodinta_valiuta
union
select
from [išlaidos pajamos]
```

and rezult is

```
suvienodinta_valiuta        tipas                   narioID
160,004                     Paj                     2
200,00                      Paj                     1
414,336                     Paj                     2
500,00                  Paj                     2
```

nows my proglem is here i have multiple  suvienodinta valiuta with same narioID
however i vant to sum it up thet every single narioID would have only 1 valiue 
example of what i vant to recieve

```
suvienodinta_valiuta        tipas                   narioID
1074,34                     Paj                     2
200,00                      Paj                     1
```

Biggest problem is that I need that structure of `select ( select ....)`

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: You are missing the selection list on the second `select` (that after the `union`).

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what the last part

```
union
select
from [išlaidos pajamos]
```

of your statement is doing, as it is missing the select list. Thus I assume for now that it is not part of your query and only dal with the rest of it. In that case, you should use `sum` and `group by` as follows:

Include the first expression from after the first `select` to before the `as suvienodinta_valiuta` in `sum()`, and append `group by tipas, narioID` before the final `order by`:

```
select  sum(suma*(select top 1 [Enantis kursas]
from [išlaidos pajamos] isp
join Kursas as k on ISP.[valiutos trumpinys]=k.[valiutos trumpinys]
where k.[Kurso Laikas] between '2000-12-30' and (select laikas2
from [išlaidos pajamos]
where Aprašymo_Id=ISL.Aprašymo_Id)
and k.[valiutos trumpinys]=(select [valiutos trumpinys]
from [išlaidos pajamos]
where Aprašymo_Id=ISL.Aprašymo_Id)                                            
order by [Kurso Laikas] desc)) as suvienodinta_valiuta, tipas, narioID
from [išlaidos pajamos] ISL
join Tipas as T on T.Aprašymo_Id=ISL.Aprašymo_Id
where T.tipas='Paj' and ISL.laikas2 between '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31 23:59:59:999'
group by tipas, narioID
order by suvienodinta_valiuta
```